# Jboss 7.1.1 ssl (https) configuration

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x, keytool

I'm trying to enable the ssl(https) in my jboss 7.1.1 application. Below are the steps that i tried

1. Received root.crt, intermediate .crt and servercertificate.crt from the certification provider
2. Executed the below commands

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias jboss7 -keyalg RSA -keystore [Common Name].keystore -validity 365
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file [root certificate].crt -keystore [Common Name].keystore
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file [intermediate certificate].crt -keystore [Common Name].keystore
   keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server -file [Common Name].crt -keystore [Common Name].keystore
   ```
3. Included the generated keystore in standalone.xml file

   ```
   <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
           <ssl name="jboss7-ssl" key-alias="jboss7" password="password" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/server.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
       </connector>
   ```

and restarted the server.

My page now loading with the https://localhost:8443/project, but it says

```
    certificate (invalid) and "This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store."
```

Could someone direct me to the mistake that I caused.

Comment: You generated the key with alias `jboss7`, but you imported the server cert to alias `server`. You must **import the server cert (or chain) _to the privatekey alias_** namely `jboss7`. Also to be clear you show the filename as `[Common Name].keystore` in the commands but `server.keystore` in the XML; these must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

keystore should not generate as a separate process. It needs to be generated at the time of creation the CSR. If that was not done then in windows there is an option to export the *.pfx from the created CSR.  Once it is done then this *.pfx can be used to create the keystore using keytool generation.

Thanks